# VicBot Dice Roller (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm going to be honest: I don't really know what I'm doing.

I'd like to make it so VicBot (for Python 2.7) can "roll" "dice" on the command "/roll xdy" with x being the number of die and y being the number of sides on those die.

So, more directly I need to be able to request x variables ≥y, and have them displayed "(variable) + (variable) = (sum)"

All of VicBot can be found here: https://github.com/Vicyorus/VicBot

(In case you were wondering: I did accidentally post this question before I was finished.)

Comment: I've just edited to improve the code formatting, but I didn't really understand your third paragraph, so its formatting remains a little bit odd. Perhaps you can clarify what you mean by "x variables ≥y" (e.g. with a concrete example)?

Comment: By x I'm referring to the number of "dice" and by y I'm referring to the number of sides on that "dice" which would correlate to the highest number you could receive. So "2d6" or "2 variables less than or equal to 6". Let's say the numbers chosen are 3 and 6 being displayed in what I mean by "(variable 1) + (variable 2) = (sum)" would be "3 + 6 = 9" I'll also try to clarify that paragraph a bit in my post.

Comment: If you were doing this in a console program, would you know how to do the random number part of the problem? That is, are you confused just about the chat-bot part of the problem, or more about computing the results for `3d6`? I've never heard of `VicBot` and don't really have any interest in reading large amounts of code to learn about it, but I could throw together an answer about the random number stuff, if that was what you were actually asking about.

Comment: It's a pretty straight forward bot. My problem lies in the random number stuff, I haven't had too much of a problem editing the bot so far, I just really don't know what I'm doing, and thought I should give anyone who decides to help me all the information I have. I don't even know where to begin with the computing.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example(https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), especially the *minimal* part. Your question becomes much easier to answer once you've removed the unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about your chatbot, nor do I really want to dig through all the code you've included in your question (it's not even clear to me if any of it is code that you've written, rather than example code that comes with the bot).

What I can do is address the die rolling stuff. That's pretty easy. All you need is Python's `random` module and some string manipulation and formatting code.

```
import random

def roll_dice(dice_string):
    """Parse a string like "3d6" and return a string showing the die rolls and their sum"""
    number_of_dice, number_of_sides = map(int, dice_string.split("d"))
    rolls = [random.randint(1, number_of_sides) for _ in range(number_of_dice)]
    output_string = "{} = {}".format(" + ".join(map(str(rolls)), sum(rolls))
    return output_string
```

Example output:

```
>>> roll_dice("5d6")
'6 + 6 + 5 + 5 + 6 = 28'
>>> roll_dice("5d6")
'1 + 5 + 1 + 2 + 2 = 11'
>>> roll_dice("3d100")
'16 + 83 + 56 = 155'
>>> roll_dice("1d20")
'18 = 18'
```

Hopefully the code is pretty self explanatory. The four statements in the function each do one thing: parsing the input, generating the requested random numbers, formatting them into a string for output, and finally returning the string. The second line, which does the actual random number generation might be useful to extract as a separate function (taking integer arguments and returning a list of integers).